# Implementing android app in multi language

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0, hindi

I am new to the android and android studio.
I want to develop an App for Indian farmers. Now the App will have support for multiple language i.e. Hindi, English, and Gujarati. I am planning to provide a simple UI to user to choose his preferred language. The home page of the app will ask user for his preferred language. 
Now how can I implement the app so that when user click on his preferred language, all the texts in app will appear in that language?
Also, when giving options of languages to the user the options should be in the same language for example Hindi option will be written in Hindi fonts.

Comment: Hi..Check this [link](http://www.androhub.com/android-building-multi-language-supported-app/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official doc. to make your app support multiple language, find it [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html).
There are also a lot of tutorial on ho to do what you ask, for example: [this one](https://www.coderefer.com/android-multi-language-support/)